# How to compare two string values in jolt

Tags: json, equality, jolt

I want to filter out the input JSON based on two field values of input JSON.

**Input JSON**

```json
[
  {
    "from_Store": "Test1",
    "to_Store": "Test1",
    "items": [
      {
        "UPC": "8240959370255",
        "shippedQuantity": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "from_Store": "Test2",
    "to_Store": "Test3",
    "items": [
      {
        "UPC": "8240959370210",
        "shippedQuantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

1. If the values of the **from_Store** and **to_Store** do not match, then keep that complete element of the map in the output JSON.
2. If the values match, then the entire element should not be in the output

**Expected output JSON**

```json
[
  {
    "from_Store": "Test2",
    "to_Store": "Test3",
    "items": [
      {
        "UPC": "8240959370210",
        "shippedQuantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there any function to compare the strings in Jolt?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exchange key-value pairs for `to_Store` and `from_Store` attributes whether an array is formed or not per each node. If array is formed, then we'll get only **1** element, eg. values of the attributes are equal. Otherwise, we'll get **2** elements, so, we'll keep them as result such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*_*": "Cnt[&1].Count.@0" // to represent both of the attributes with unique underscores, eg. "from_store" and "to_store"
      },
      "@": "Original" // replicate the initial JSON value
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Cnt": {
        "*": {
          "Count": "=size(@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Count": "&1",
          "*": "&1.&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "1": { // the second component
          "2": { // keep the value if its value is 2
            "@(2,[0])": "[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]